# Pegar dados restantes através do ID do array

Tags: php, mysql

Como faço para pegar os dados que não foram passados via $_POST, mas já estão salvos na mesma tabela que estou recebendo alguns dados, como ID,NOME_PRODUTO,etc., em um array, que recebe dados de vários produtos.

```
 //POST em array que recebo

$valor_unitario = $_POST['valorunitario'];
$nome-produto= $_POST['nome_produto'];
$quant_produto = $_POST['quant_produto'];
$subtotal = $_POST['subtotal'];
$id_produto = $_POST['id_produto'];


//AQUI INSERE OS ARRAYS NO BANCO DE DADOS, RECEBE OS PRODUTOS ADICIONADOS VIA POST (AQUI QUERO SALVAR O RESTANTE DOS CAMPOS DO PRODUTO ATRAVÉS DO ID DELES.
$i=0;
$sql= "INSERT INTO `log_nfe_produtos` (`NOME_PRODUTO`, `VALOR_UNITARIO`, `QUANT_PRODUTO`, `SUBTOTAL`, `ID_EMPRESA`,`ID_NF`) VALUES ";

foreach($nome_produto as $p){

$sql=$sql."('$p','$valor_unitario[$i]','$quant_produto[$i]','$subtotal[$i]','1','$cod_pedido[$i]'),";

$i++;

}

$sqlFinal = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql)-1);

$sqlFinal2 = $conn->prepare("$sqlFinal");

$sqlFinal2->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

De acordo com o Manual do [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.lastinsertid.php) há uma funcionalidade chamada `lastInsertId` que tem como objetivo acessar o `id` da última linha ou valor de seqüência inserido.

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("...");
$stmt->execute();
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Se você quiser fazê-lo com função SQL em vez da API PDO, você faria isso como uma consulta de seleção normal:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$lastId = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Um exemplo para o seu caso ficaria assim:

```
$dados_persistidos = [];

foreach($nome_produto as $p){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `log_nfe_produtos` (`NOME_PRODUTO`, `VALOR_UNITARIO`, `QUANT_PRODUTO`, `SUBTOTAL`, `ID_EMPRESA`,`ID_NF`) VALUES ";
    $sql .= "('$p','$valor_unitario[$i]','$quant_produto[$i]','$subtotal[$i]','1','$cod_pedido[$i]'),";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    /*
       Salva o último id inserido no banco no array 
       para posteriormente poder acessá-los
    */
    array_push($dados_persistidos, $db->lastInsertId());  
}
```

Depois com os `id's` salvos no array `$dados_persistidos`, um simples *select* poderá ser feito, assim:

```
$id_s = implode(',', $dados_persistidos);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `log_nfe_produtos` WHERE id_log_nfe_produtos in ('.$id_s.')';
$consulta = $pdo->query($sql);
$resultados = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($resultados);
```

Espero que te ajude. E ajuste o código a sua necessidade.

Obs.: Quebrei o *script sql* em duas parte para a barra de rolagem não ficar muito grande.